# When I try "Jupyter Lab" In Anaconda, I get ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated! I already tried "conda install pywin32" and no I am not using miniconda. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue,

I ran pip uninstall pywin32 (twice because i had two versions)

then tried installing pywin32 and got this error:
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
conda-repo-cli 1.0.4 requires pathlib, which is not installed.

so I ran pip install pathlib

and BOOM finally able to use Jupyter Notebook.